# Peculiar way of writing limits of integration

Tags: integration, notation

I'm taking a course on ordinary differential equations, and in the last couple classes, my professor has written several integrals like this, with no lower limit:
$$\int^xf(t)\ dt$$
From what I understand, he intends for it to be functionally the same as $\int f(x)\ dx$, so I'm wondering what the purpose of this notation is. Is it commonly used? (Our textbook doesn't  use it, though.) Is it for some sort of clarity? Or is it perhaps just a quirk of his to write integrals like this?

---

**Example:**
In class today, we were talking about calculating integrating factors. At one point, we were working on solving the equation $xy'+2y=\sin x$ and he wrote this on the board:
$$\mu(x)=\exp\left[\int^x \frac2t \ dt\right]=e^{2\ln(x)}=x^2$$
I'm perfectly comfortable with finding integrating factors, but is there a reason not to write this without the $t$? It looks nicer to me as $$\exp\left[\int\frac2x\ dx\right]$$

Comment: Why haven't you asked your professor this question??

Comment: People have asked him in class multiple times, and he has yet to give a real answer. I believe he's said the book uses it (which it doesn't), and he's also said that it makes things simpler, which I don't understand. I'm just wondering if anyone else has seen or used this notation.

Comment: I think the notation probably means the integral is still a definite integral but the lower bound can be chosen conveniently to make the result simple. For example, in $\mu(x)$, the lower bound for $t$ is implicitly chosen to be $1$ to cancel any constant.

Comment: I had not seen that notation before, I think is just a notation used for your teacher. It seems he don't care about the constant appearing when integrating, that make sense in ODE context. But I think that here we only can speculate.

Comment: @Zhuoran He That makes sense; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have seen the notation
$$\int^x f(t) \, dt,$$
it is used more for convenience than anything else. Here the upper limit of $x$ is used to remind one that the variable of integration needs to be changed back to $x$ after the integration with respect to $t$ has been performed.

In your particular case I think your professor is using such notation so as not to confuse the variable $x$ found in the integrating factor $\mu (x)$ with the variable used in the indefinite integral.